# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedRecipientId'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have a problem with my Post method, when posting the form it throw this error

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SelectedRecipientId'.
```

I have a Listbox is empty when getting the view then i will fill it up using textbox input then when postinf the form i encounter that Error, can anyone help me figure what the problem is?

this is my viewModel

```
public class SendViewModel
{
    ...

    [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public string ScheduleTime { get; set; }

    //public string[] SelectedRecipientId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

This is my MVC Listbox View

```
<div>
                        <label><strong>Recipients</strong> </label>
                        @Html.ListBox("SelectedRecipientId", Model.Recipients, new { id = "recipientList", style = "width: 250px; height: 160px;", name = "SelectedRecipientId" })
                    </div>
```

This the Controller am using to Get & Post the value

```
 //
    // GET: /Message/Send
    public ActionResult Send()
    {


        SendViewModel model = new SendViewModel();

        model.Recipients = GetRecipients();

        model.Times = GetTimes();


        return View(model);

    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(string message, string[] SelectedRecipientId)
    {
        var model = new SendViewModel();

        model.Times = GetTimes();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        var User = GetLoggedInUserID();
```

...

```
        var getContactId = _contactService.GetContactById(model.SenderId);


        var SenderId = senderIdList.ToString();

            if(SenderId == null)
            {
                SenderId = defaultSenderId;
            }



        if (SenderId != null && message != null && SelectedRecipientId != null)
        {

                if (model.ScheduledDate == DateTime.Now)
                {
                    _messageService.SendMessage(User, SenderId, model.Message, SelectedRecipientId);

                    if (groupListing != null)
                    {
                        _messageService.SendGroupMessage(User, SenderId, model.GroupId, model.Message, SelectedRecipientId);
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("/UserAccount/SendMessageConfirmation");
                }


                if (model.ScheduledDate != DateTime.Now)
                {
                    _messageService.AddScheduledMessage(User, SenderId, model.Message, model.ScheduledDate, SelectedRecipientId);
                }

            }
            else
                ViewBag.Error = "Sender ID, Message Text and Recipient are Required to send your message";
        return View(model);
        }


        model.Recipients = GetRecipients();
        return View(model);
    }
```

this is the GetRecipients() method

```
 private List<SelectListItem> GetRecipients()
    {
        var recipientList = new List<SelectListItem>() 
        {};

        return recipientList;
    }
```

This is the model Am posting it to:

```
 public class SentMessage : IDataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime SendDate { get; set; }
    public int RecipientCount { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public double CreditsUsed { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<MessageRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }

}
```

public class MessageRecipient : IDataObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public SentMessage Message { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        ...
    }

The service method am using also goes like this

```
int SendMessage(int userId, string senderId, string message, IEnumerable<string> recipients);
```

Thats all...

please I need help on how I can successfully post the listbox values to that IEnumerable recipients... Thanks in advance

Comment: Note Please am Not Getting any collection from the database to the listBox, am only posting the values inside it... Thankyou

Comment: Yes because I have pass a parameter for that because I thought it was the cause

Comment: Take a property in ur class SendViewModel..... public string SelectedRecipientId{ get; set; }

Comment: It will still throw the error after i take it

Comment: If you inspect your rendered html, do you actually see the name property of your item set to `SelectedRecipientId`